# lxml alternative in Java?

Tags: java, python, lxml

I have been extensively using lxml for developing algos. But now, due to [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134973/approach-to-achieve-speed-and-practicality) issues, I have to migrate to Java. Moral is, can I find as awesome as lxml dom parser in Java?

**> Key requirements :**

> 1) feature like text_content()
>    2) iterchildren and
>    3) iterparent() and itersiblings()--- (if xpath is there, I think we can
>    do such traversing, not sure).

Jsoup is famous there, but not sure if all can be done. I just want to port algorithms not heavy rewriting. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Why Java :
I am doing complex nlp and dom parsing tasks. Python is first choice and will remain.Writing c-extension is one thing, and performing complex nlp tasks is another, and merging two is yet another thing. Hence Java. Nothing offensive.

Comment: There are actually wrappers for `libxml2` in Java, although I doubt any of them are as nice as `lxml` is in Python. Especially if you're looking for `iterfoo`-style methods, because Java doesn't have anything like Python's iterator protocol, generators, etc. that makes them doable/useful. Trying to translate Python code into Pythonic Java code is as bad an idea as going the other direction; you're going to want to write idiomatic Java code. Which means you should be looking for the best, most Java-ish DOM library (maybe Xerces-J? I'm a bit out of date…), not the most Python-ish one.

Comment: Also, are you sure you actually need to port to Java for performance? What parts of your code are slow? Does it help if you run your code in PyPy instead of CPython? What about just rewriting the slow part in C (or Cython) and leaving the rest in Python? Or, equivalently, rewriting the slow part in Java while leaving the rest in Python (running in Jython instead of CPython)?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks. I even tried embedding Python in C. But GIL (among others) gives no significant performance boost.

Comment: Jython may be an option. But key concern is performance. I am starting up, so need to optimize cpu/memory part as well as write fast code. Java consumes more cpu than C++, but I found it a terrible idea to write something like lxml and nlp tasks in C.

Comment: First, nobody suggested embedding in C; just building C extensions in Python. Second, it's very easy to release the GIL around your hotspot code inside a C extension. But if all you're looking for is core-parallelism, just use multiprocessing instead of threads. More importantly: do you even know where your hotspots are? Just rewriting your code over and over until one version is finally fast is not how you optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Saxon is your best bet in my opinion http://saxon.sourceforge.net . A bunch of examples can be found in this download of saxon-resources9-4.zip found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.4/ like xpath expressions:

```
    XPathExpression findLine =
        xpe.compile("//LINE[contains(., $word)]");
    XPathExpression findLocation =
        xpe.compile("concat(ancestor::ACT/TITLE, ' ', ancestor::SCENE/TITLE)");
    XPathExpression findSpeaker =
        xpe.compile("string(ancestor::SPEECH/SPEAKER[1])");
```

Comment: thanks. will try that if I can use it to iterate over child nodes and parent nodes. Thans.

Answer (score 0):

[xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) is a great for xml. You would use xerces via [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/intro/index.html).